# Strange Array Scope issue with Jquery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to create an array, then on mouseup() populate it with data then access it down stream with one of the [jquery slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range-vertical) modules in the console like so:

```
day_range = new Array();

$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
          orientation: "vertical",
          range: true,
          values: [ 30, 45 ],
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ]+" Days" );
            beginDay = ui.values[ 0 ];
            endDay = ui.values[ 1 ]             
          }
});
$( "#amount" ).val($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
          " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) +" Days" );

$(".ui-slider-handle").mouseup(function(){
  day_range.length = 0;

  day_range.push(beginDay, endDay);     
});

console.log(day_range);
```

**Problem:** In FF, I am able to see the empty array upon loading with the message "There are no child objects". This is odd to me, because i created an array up stream not an array of objects unless this is automatically being done. Now when I move the slider, I see that my array gets populated in FF, but not in Chrome. When I try to access the indexes with:

```
console.log(day_range[0]);
```

It is undefined in both. I feel that this might be a trivial issue where I am making a stupid mistake, but I could not find anything on this specific issue. In reviewing the [Jquery scope documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/scope/), it looks like what I am doing is correct. Here is the code in action in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G4ScL/). But, something is obviously missing. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance. It might help if when you access the jsFiddle like, you open your js logs in your browser to see what is happening. Particularly in FF.

Comment: You should provide a jsFiddle so we can test it

Comment: I'm not clear what the problem is. Here's a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/nehek/1/edit

Comment: @A.Wolff I have added the jsFiddle option as requested.

Comment: The code inside a `.mouseup()` handler is executed *later*, when that event actually occurs. That's well after the `console.log()` is called, rendering the *then* still empty `Array` to console.

Comment: So that: http://jsfiddle.net/G4ScL/1/ ???

Comment: @A.Wolff what did you change?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Yes Jonathan, but when one changes the number of days, the console does infact populate in FF but not in Chrome. See the jsFiddle link in the post.

Comment: Where are you using `console.log(day_range[0]);`? I think that's the root of your issue. The array IS being populated correctly.

Comment: @Mr.Concolato The console may be showing you a live or delayed view of the `Array`. If its modified, especially before opening a detailed view, the console may show it with modifications. But, those still are made *after* the logging.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski  So then how to do I access the array? Is the array actually there? Not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that if you create a sort of global variable with respect to nested functions, that you can modify that variable within a nested function and then see the changed variable downstream. Like so:

```
function main(){
  var a = 1;
  function one(){
     a = a + 2;
  } 
  one();
  console.log(a); // a = 3
}
```

I have thought that there might be a way to access an **event based function** in the same way, and there isn't way to do this. The only way to achieve what i was looking for is by doing this:

```
$(".ui-slider-handle").mouseup(function(){
  day_range.length = 0;

  day_range.push(beginDay, endDay);  
  console.log(day_range[0]);

  //more code here like an ajax call etc
});
```

Lesson learned, thanks to all for your comments. My apologies for any confusion, particularly on my part ;). Now if anyone can improve on this answer, then i will give you the credit for solving the issue. I just wanted to share my conclusion. But again, if you found it helpful ...